# Time or date difference using remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

When remoting into 2008 R2 we are getting this message.

`Remote Desktop cannot verify the identity of the remote computer because there is a time or date difference between your computer and the remote computer. Make sure your computer's clock is set to the correct time, and then try connecting again.`

I have checked the server and the time is correct.

Checking the event logs it is saying `The RPC server is unavailable` I'm not sure if this is related.

Additional note: We have Nagios monitoring, and it has reported `Result from smbclient not suitable.`

Comment: You said you checked the server but what about the client? The time on the server and client need to be close to each other (I believe within 5 minutes though I'm willing to be corrected) for the kerberos authentication to work.

Comment: Hi. The client's time is correct also.

Comment: Restarting the server, solved the issue.

Comment: FYI... To anyone reading this in an AD or domain environment. If you have a domain controller or many of them, you might take a quick look at the date and time of the domain controller servers if you run into this when you RDP into machines that give this message. In my case I guess a CMOS battery went out and when the server rebooted after an unexpected power outage, the time did not come back up correctly. Simply adjusting the DC to have the correct time and then rebooting the VM machine that was giving the message corrected. Just restarted the VM before correcting the DC time did not fix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Restarting the server and installing all of the latest updates solved the issue.

Comment: Of course it did, it's Windows! ;-P

Comment: +1 worked for me also (although no new updates were needed).

Comment: In my case, using the IP address instead of the machine name did the trick. It's a workaround though.

Comment: @Matias Using the IP Address worked for me. Thanks. Do you happen to know why this is?

Answer (score 6):

A little old but there are several other options for this issue like DNS issues... please take a look at this link:

http://www.chicagotech.net/remoteissues/rdc4.htm

> In my case, it is DNS issue. After we moved one Hyper-V VM from one
>   physical server to another physical server, we receive this error:
>   "Your computer could not connect to another console session on the
>   remote computer because you already have a console session in
>   progress." If I use IP address, I can login without any problems.

But yeah, most of the times just rebooting the server fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I used the machine's IP address instead of the hostname when making the connection, and that circumvented the error.

This is obviously not a complete fix but it was a very useful workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure port TCP 88 isn't blocked by a firewall;  Kerberos uses this port in addition to 3389 to authenticate the session, if you have Network Level Authentication enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue was static IP. Once I switched it to dynamic the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had left a VPN connection open on the machine (to a different time zone, don't know if that's important)
I logged on directly and closed the connection and the error went away.

Comment: Hi, please complete your answer detail, as is, it's not really an answer.

Comment: The issue was that I had a VPN connection open on the machine, that kept me from connecting to it. I closed the connection and the error went away. This won't work in every situation... but it worked in mine. Just trying to be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I more mean your sentence is not complete in your answer, it miss the end, you can just edit that to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

My users have this error if their password for a remote computer is saved locally in "Remote Desktop" settings and it's wrong. This is 100% repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

And one more potential cause.  ipV6.  Disable it.  Whenever I have a machine with ipV6 enabled, there are network problems.  I JUST had a backup server that was inaccessible with RDP.  I WAS able to access it by using the IP address instead of the backup server name.  That's quite telling.  It took me a while to find the issue.  My time wasn't wasted.  I at least got to clean up some old DNS entries.  But the solution was: go to network and disable ipV6.  Problem solved.  Gawd, I hate ipV6.  A security and reliability nightmare.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/509282)