# server with public IP cannot be accessed internally

Tags: windows, ip, windows-server-2012-r2, external-ip

Most of our servers only have private IPs. I am assigning additional public IP to one of our servers (server A), keeping its private IP at the same time. Here's what happens:

1. Server A can be accessed externally by its assigned public IP.
2. Server A can be accessed internally by its assigned public IP.
3. Server A **cannot** be accessed internally by its private IP, remote access error message[1] below.
4. Server A **cannot** access other internal servers by their private IPs.
5. **Problems in point 3 and point 4 goes away for a while after server A gets restarted, but they come back after some time.**

Can anyone tell me what's going on? Thanks a lot.
.

Additional info:

1. We are using all windows servers.
2. Using juniper router.
3. remote access error message[1]: *remote desktop cannot verify the identity of the remote computer because there is a time or date difference between your computer and the remote computer. Make sure your computer's clock is set to the correct time, and then try connecting again. If the problem occurs again, contact your network administrator or the owner of the remote computer.*

Comment: You should include details like the IP addresses (or an obfuscated alternative) and what method you have used to assign this external IP internally.  If you did it with some config on the juniper, then include that.  It would also be helpful if you could define what you mean by 'cannot be accessed'.  Do you mean you cannot ping it, you cannot resolve names, you cannot browse file shares or what.  That happens if you do a traceroute to the IP?

Answer (score 0):

Windows update may fix your issue. I am assuming that you are trying to connect using the IP address not the DNS name you may have assigned to your public and private IP address. This could avoid any DNS issue.

[Time or date difference using remote desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/381477/time-or-date-difference-using-remote-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

How are you assigning a public IP to the server? Do you have 2 NIC's on the server? Is it a physical/virtual machine? I need more information to determine what might be happening. It could be possible that there's another machine on your network with the same static private IP address that's causing a conflict. You can ask someone in the NOC or network department to do an arp lookup on the mac address for your server to see what IP it's grabbing, and then lookup that same IP address to make sure no one else is using the same IP by mistake.